# How to get from the Elements type the title of each article from a new line?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am learning how to write Telegram bots.

### The idea of a bot

The user writes a keyword related to the design and parsing the site I need and finds articles that have this keyword.

---

For now, I just want to display the titles of all the articles that are on the site. The problem is that when I get all the elements

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://my-dom.design/dizajn-interera/")
    .userAgent("Chrome/4.0.249.0 Safari/532.5")
    .referrer("https://yandex.ru/")
    .get();
Elements article = doc.select("h3.elementor-post__title a ");
Elements description = doc.select("div.elementor-post__excerpt p");
```

and then transfer the `Elements article` to the code of the bot itself, which, when responded, gives these `Elements article`, then they are all in one line. There is no separation of the article titles, they all go in one row, but I want each name to be a new `h3` block started on a new line. How can I do this, please tell me?

Answer (score 1):

Bascially, your `article` looks somewhat like this:

```html
<a href="https://foo.bar/1">first link</a>
<a href="https://foo.bar/2">second link</a>
<a href="https://foo.bar/3">...</a>
```

As you can see, this will be rendered in a single line.

IIUC, you want something like this:

```html
<h3><a href="https://foo.bar/1">first link</a></h3>
<h3><a href="https://foo.bar/2">second link</a></h3>
<h3><a href="https://foo.bar/3">...</a></h3>
```

You can wrap each title link inside an `h3` element like this:

```
Elements article = doc.select("h3.elementor-post__title a ");
article = new Elements(
    article.stream()
           .map(e -> e.wrap("<h3></h3>").parent())
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

But in your case, this is madness. A much simpler solution is to alter the query to search less deep. In other words, change:

```
Elements article = doc.select("h3.elementor-post__title a ");
```

to:

```
Elements article = doc.select("h3.elementor-post__title");
```